# Find out which class the element was identified by

Tags: jquery

I'm making a small fluid grid system for a website, which will have classes .g1 to .g5.

I want to take all elements with one of those classes, remove only that class, wrap them in a container, and then add the class which was removed to the new container. Problem is, I have no idea how to find out by what class the element was identified, and add the same one to the container.

I'm doing this to be able to add fixed margin between elements.

Comment: You're looking to do this manually?  You can see what rules and therefore which classes match in the browser developer tools.

Comment: When you say dynamically, I assume you mean that the user clicks on an element, then you use the class for that element as the starting point.  Is it this class that you want to identify?

Comment: Sorry everybody, I meant fluid not dynamic. .g1 for example has width: 20%, and .g5 has width: 100%. Nothing is clicked, this is supposed to run on load.

Comment: @NovAlex I modified my code. is this you want?

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not just doing this server-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to find our which element is clicked.Than simply remove its class and append to `conatiner` or add`.container` class

```
$("div[class^=g]").click(function(){
var cls=$(this).attr("class");
$(this).revoveClass($(this).attr("class"));
$("#container").addClass(cls)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please read the question again. This is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get using regexpression. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaHq4/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("div[class*='g']").each(function(){      
        var cls = this.className.match(/g\d{1}\s/);
        if(cls){
            $(this).removeClass(cls[0].trim());
        }
    }); 
});​
```

Comment: Chrome dev console says: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [class=^g]

Comment: I see it only works if the g# class is first, if it has for example class="box g2" it doesn't work anymore. Any way to make it work if it's not first? Thank You.

Comment: Oh, I made the changes see jsfiddle.

Comment: Now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null, even though it works in jsfiddle. I assume it means no class matches the expression, but why does it work in jsfiddle? What could cause this?

Comment: I think $(this) targets the var, not the div, because there is no change. No error in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remember the class you removed to add it to another element? tried already  jquery data http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ ?